# Unity3D - Transfer Data between a Mobile and a Desktop Application

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, desktop-application

I have a desktop application to store various data in a database (up to 10k datasets).
Then i have multiple mobile devices (Android and Apple) to collect data by user-input (up to 2k datasets).

Assuming a not existing wlan or internet connection: what is the best way to transfer or synchronize data between Desktop - Mobile and vice versa ?
I would try to copy the db-file to the mobile device and update the mobile-db via script comparation (slow..).
A) How to access usb-connected mobile storage via desktop-app?
B) How to find, read and write those files on mobile?

Assuming i have wlan if i come home with mobile and dont wanna mess with usb.
C) Transfer data via multiplayer-communication-stuff? Like the two running apps communicate via chat-like system. One dataset per message; then parsed to desktop-db. ... seems also slow.

Best solution would be.. both ^^ the user should be able to choose.
What do u folks think ? :)

Comment: Usually you do such a thing with a central internet database (Firebase is a good one) and whenever a device goes online sync the data. Even for a local multiplayer you need a Wlan connection and one of your apps must be the server.

Comment: U r right but the thing is: its an app for collecting geo-data for scientific purpose.
Outside in the field its possible i wont have internet access on mobile. And even if i return to base its maybe to much to setup an internet database just to evaluate the data.
Despite that: the ability to do it with and online database will be given. But i need the described alternatives as backup.
I try an altered chat with Unity built in Network-Manager and a file-based alternative where the files have to be moved manually. But im not sure if its fast enough. I dont wanna wait 2hrs for some data ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can tether a hotspot point from your mobile, connect your pc to this network and use sockets or http requests between your applications.